# R.java error “; ” expected & <identifier> expected

Tags: r.java-file, build-error

I am getting errors in `R.java` when compiling my project.
I tried to solve it but I could not, does anyone help me?

**R.java:**

```
public static final int drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000=0x7f07002c;
public static final int drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015=0x7f07002d;
public static final int drawable/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000=0x7f07002e;
public static final int drawable/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_015=0x7f07002f;
public static final int drawable/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001=0x7f070030;
public static final int drawable/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012=0x7f070031;
public static final int drawable/abc_ic_star_half_black_16dp=0x7f070032;
public static final int drawable/abc_ic_star_half_black_36dp=0x7f070033;
public static final int drawable/abc_ic_star_half_black_48dp=0x7f070034;
public static final int drawable/abc_list_focused_holo=0x7f070035;
public static final int drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark=0x7f070036;
public static final int drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light=0x7f070037;
public static final int drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark=0x7f070038;
public static final int drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light=0x7f070039;
public static final int drawable/abc_scrubber_control_off_mtrl_alpha=0x7f07003a;
public static final int drawable/abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_000=0x7f07003b;
public static final int drawable/abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_005=0x7f07003c;
public static final int drawable/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha=0x7f07003d;
public static final int drawable/abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha=0x7f07003e;
public static final int drawable/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha=0x7f07003f;
public static final int drawable/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha=0x7f070040;
public static final int drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha=0x7f070041;
public static final int drawable/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha=0x7f070042;
public static final int drawable/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha=0x7f070043;
public static final int drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled=0x7f070044;
public static final int drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused=0x7f070045;
public static final int drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal=0x7f070046;
public static final int drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed=0x7f070047;
public static final int drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled=0x7f070048;
public static final int drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused=0x7f070049;
public static final int drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal=0x7f07004a;
public static final int drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed=0x7f07004b;
public static final int drawable/notification_bg_low_normal=0x7f07004c;
public static final int drawable/notification_bg_low_pressed=0x7f07004d;
public static final int drawable/notification_bg_normal_pressed=0x7f07004e;
public static final int drawable/notify_panel_notification_icon_bg=0x7f07004f;
public static final int edit_query=0x7f070050;
public static final int end=0x7f070051;
public static final int end_padder=0x7f070052;
public static final int expand_activities_button=0x7f070053;
public static final int expanded_menu=0x7f070054;
public static final int home=0x7f070055;
public static final int homeAsUp=0x7f070056;
public static final int icon=0x7f070057;
public static final int icon_group=0x7f070058;
public static final int icon_only=0x7f070059;
public static final int ifRoom=0x7f07005a;
public static final int image=0x7f07005b;
public static final int img_prog_frame=0x7f07005c;
public static final int info=0x7f07005d;
public static final int layout/notification_template_part_chronometer=0x7f07005e;
```

http://prntscr.com/k4uydg

http://prntscr.com/k4uygr

I have already looked for errors in **strings.xml** but found nothing.

Comment: you can't have a forward-slash in a variable name for starters

Comment: perhaps replace the slash with an underscore, e.g. `public static final int drawable_abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000=0x7f07002c;`

Comment: Thank you, but where will I make this modification? Because R.java is auto-generated and I do not find these lines in the strings.xml files

Comment: The project is from an earlier version of Android Studio, with Sdk and Gradle as well.
After I updated that the error occurred